# Getting error while Creating a MSVC Project in libraries "You have selected a library, Please choose a folder Instead" Give any solution to create it

Tags: visual-studio-2010, qt4

Whenever I am creating a new project using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 in libraries provided from Windows 7, I am getting an error: `You have sellected a library. Please select a folder instead`. The same error is coming in my project while I am browsing for an existing directory using Qt.

My code is as below:

```
QString directory = QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(this,
                               tr("Select a directory to store"), QDir::currentPath());
```

Comment: Any suggestions are appreciated. My aim is to get the directory path when user selects a directory after clicking on a **Browse...** button _even if library is selected_.